# Linear indexing of Matlab matrices in MEX file

Tags: c, matlab, matrix, mex, matrix-indexing

I have a NxN symmetric matrix F of the following form

```
F_11 F_12 F_13 ... F_1N 

F_21 ...      

F_31

.
.
.

F_N1 F_N2 F_N3 ... F_NN
```

with each submatrices F_IJ of size m x m.

This matrix is created in MatLab, and will be used in a C-programm. So the values are stored in a vector columnwise. (E.g the vector will be of the form : (F_11_11,F_11_21,F_11_31,...F_11_m1,F_21_11,...F_NN_(m-1)m,F_NN_mm).

My question is the following: For readability I would like to define in C a way to access the values of F, given the indices (I,J) of the location of the first submatrix, and the indices (i,j) of the location of value in the submatrix. How can I link the linear indexing of the matrix to the (I,J,i,j) indices?

Comment: You've tagged C++, but in the question, you ask about C. Which did you mean to ask about?

Comment: I am confused by your naming convention. Can you provide a small example?

Comment: A confusing way to describe a 4 dimensional matrix.

Comment: @user2079303 : Yes, you are right, the tag should be C.

Comment: @Daniel : Yes, true... but how would you better represent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume all indices to be zero based, as usual in C/C++. If you want to use Matlab style one based indices, subtract one from each index.

I didn't check it, but I guess your index should be...

```
int idx = I*m+J*N*m*m+i+j*N*m;
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed does the trick. Maybe in the future an explanation to how you got to this would be helpful (In case of an error for example, to see where the mistake could lie)

Comment: OK, the explanation: your complete matrix F is N*m x N*m. In F, the element (i,j) of the submatrix F_IJ has indices (k,l)=(i+I*m,j+J*m). Note that all indices zero based. F is now saved in an N^2*m^2 long C array, such that the matrix element (k,l) of F is saved at array index idx=k+l*N*m. Putting both index transformations together results in the formula I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that calculates the index. Note that in C, indices start at 0.

```
size_t index_of_2d(size_t x, size_t y, size_t n) {
    return x + y*n;
}


size_t index_of_4d(size_t I, size_t J, size_t N, size_t i, size_t j, size_t m) {
    size_t submatrix = index_of_2d(I, J, N) * m * m; // scale the index in super matrix by the size of the submatrix
    return submatrix + index_of_2d(i, j, m);
}
```